# How to write Kotlin-colloquial code to retry synchronously until timeout or success?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

After reading Kotlin documentation, I came up with the following code (which is not working - see below) to repeat a function call until it returns true, or timeout is reached.
I want to pause execution until this code block reaches timeout or success - it is not supposed to execute asynchronously.

```
Log.d(TAG, "This is the last line to be logged")
runBlocking {
    Log.d(TAG, "this line is never logged")
    try {
        withTimeout(timeoutMsL) {
            while ((isActive) && (!success)) {
                success = doSomething()
            }
        } 
    }
    catch (ex: TimeoutCancellationException) {
        Log.d(TAG, "this line is never logged either")
        doSomethingElse()
    }
}
```

`timeoutMsL` is a `Long` with typical value 50 ms.
This code is called from C++ over the JNI.  When I run it

- nothing inside the runBlocking block runs
- nothing after the runBlocking block runs
- control returns to the C++ caller
- there is an exception in the JNI, but the JNI doesn't log Kotlin or Java exception details.
- no exception is logged in adb
- when I tried surrounding the above code snippet with a try/catch/log block to catch Kotlin exceptions, nothing is logged

I have read that `runBlocking` should be avoided, but also you have to call `withTimeout` from an existing coroutine.
If I use a normal coroutine, execution of the calling function will continue before timeout /success is reached - I need to prevent this from happening.

How should this be coded in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem probably lies in `doSomething()`. Kotlin's coroutine implementation relies a lot on cooperative execution where child coroutines check flags to see if they have been cancelled (as `withTimeout()` would do). This would mean the outer coroutines will pause until they confirm the child coroutines have ended, blocking the entire function.

if `doSomething` never suspends and never checks if it is still active it will just run until completion regardless of the external situation.

To fix this, there are two options:

1. Make `doSomething()` a `suspend` function and regularly suspend with either `yield()` or `ensureActive()` to respond to cancellation.
2. Execute it on a dispatcher that is designed to interrupt normal blocking code like `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`.

Comment: I thought I covered this possibility with this line: while ((isActive) && (!success)) {.  It checks the IsActive parameter inside the withTimeout coroutine.

Comment: It would require `doSomething()` to return before that code runs, if it never returns that code never runs.

Comment: doSomething is a short function.  It should return.  I added a small runBlocking block with a single logging line, before this code, and this line is never logged either.  For some reason, my code is exiting every time it hits runBlocking.  I don't understand what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Implicitly, you have confirmed that my code is correct.  The code is inside an AAR that is part of a Xamarin Android Binding Library.  I have now proved that Xamarin doesn't recognise Kotlin coroutines.  I can't find any Xamarin library that supports them (the equivalent of org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.0.1 for Xamarin)

Comment: One last question - how could I achieve the same functionality in Kotlin without using co-routines?  I just want to keep reading data from a buffer (inside a lock), and exit when I've got a given number of bytes, or else at the timeout.

Comment: That would probably be better as its own question, rather than trying to answer it in comments.